# Is it possible to re-pass variables to a CodeIgniter library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, when creating and calling a custom library, it is possible to pass variables (parameters) to the library via a second optional variable.

**[Example taken from the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html):**

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$this->load->library('someclass', $params);
```

and

```
class Someclass {

        public function __construct($params)
        {
                // Do something with $params
        }
}
```

In some cases, it may be desirable to reload the library with a different set of parameters. However, this does not seem to be possible. When the `[...]->library()` method is called again with a new set of parameters, only the original parameters are expressed—not the new ones. The CodeIgniter documentation does not address this issue.

What are my options?

Comment: Are those params set by user?

Comment: Their values are, yes.

Comment: So you can set that conditional logic in constructor of `Someclass` don't you? It is in same request/response cycle.

Comment: User data is parsed into an array and then looped through. I need different parameters for every element in that user-provided array.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. There is no way to autoload `Someclass` with no parameters, but pass those through method arguments like `$this->someclass->method1($param1, $param2);` and `$this->someclass->method2($param3, $param4);`?

Comment: I can manually pass variables to my method, sure. The question, however, is regarding whether or not I can reload a library with a new set of parameters. I'm just exploring my options. Thanks though!